# Getting a huge amount of data from database in the most efficient way

Tags: java, database, multithreading, performance

In my application, i have to read a huge amount of data. After i have got all of my data, i put it in a list and process on it and work accordingly.

Now i was wondering if i can do anything, Anything to speed up the getting data from the database process? My database sits on a different server and i am working with java to interact with the database.

I dont have a definite size of the data, i.e. a specific number of rows that i need to process. Also I hear i can go for multithreading, but then how do go about it? since i wont know how to partition my data since it is indefinite. i.e. if the following pseudo code is to be applied

```
for(i=0 to number of partition) // Not certain on the number of partitions
    create new thread and get data.
```

Or maybe i can hash data on the basis of some attribute and later tell each thread to fetch a particular index of the map, but then how do i map it before even fetching the data?

What all possible solutions can i look into, and how do i go about it? Let me know if you need any more info.

Thanks.

Comment: How much data are we talking about? Can you perform some of your processing in the database instead? What's the current bottleneck?

Comment: I think, Multiple threads to fetch data is a good choice. You can create a model in which you need to provide total number of records to be fetched by a single thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I hear i can go for multithreading, but then how do go about it?

This is definetly a good choice to speed up querying information from a remote server.

Usually in these tasks - the IO with the server is the main bottleneck, and by multithreading - one can "ask for" multiple rows concurrently - affectively reducing the IO wait times.

> but then how do go about it?

The idea is to split the work into smaller tasks. Have a look at java [high level concurrency API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html) for more details.

One solution is to let each thread read a chunk of size `M` from the server, and repeat the process for each thread while there is still data in it (the server). Something like that (for each thread):

```
data = "start";
int chunk = threadNumber;
while (data != null) {
  requestChunk(chunk);
  chunk += numberOfThreads;
}
```

I assume here that once you are "out of bound" the server returns `null` (or `requestChunk()` processes it and returns null).

> Or maybe i can hash data on the basis of some attribute and later tell
>   each thread to fetch a particular index of the map

If you need to iterate the data, and retrieve all of it - hashing is usually a bad solution. It is very cache inefficient and the overhead is just too big for this cases.

Comment: hw do i go about the multithreading here? Kindly see the pseudo code. What can i do? Thanks